# jQuery set value of nth-child input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html and I want to set the value of the second radio button in the list to be checked. I know I can do this using the id attribute but how can I do the same 
    by using the class selector as below and chaining the input field to be checked?

```
<ul class="myOptionList">
   <li>
     <input id="1" type="radio" value="1" name="options">
     <label >one</label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="2" type="radio" value="2" name="options">
     <label >two</label>
   </li>
   ...
 </ul>

$(".myOptionList li:nth-child(2)"); // how do i chain input field and set it as checked
```

Comment: `$(".myOptionList li:nth-child(2)").find('input:radio').prop('checked',true)`

Comment: @guradio why not `$(".myOptionList li:nth-child(2) input:radio').prop('checked',true)`?

Comment: @DenisSheremet - because the question seems to be *"how do i **chain...*** "*

Comment: if you want to access as chain so you can use loop by `input type` i.e. `$('input').each(function() {})` and can write your logic

Comment: The problem here, is you're using radio button with the same *name*, that allow you to check just one of them. So to check the proper option you should access by *id* or by *value* attributes. Or change the *radio* type to *checkbox*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code may help you.

HTML

```
<ul class="myOptionList">
   <li>
     <input id="1" type="radio" value="1" name="options">
     <label >one</label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="2" type="radio" value="2" name="options">
     <label >two</label>
  </li>
```

jQuery

```
$(".myOptionList li:nth-child(2)").find('input:radio').prop('checked',true);
```

For versions of jQuery prior to 1.6, use:

```
$(".myOptionList li:nth-child(2)").find('input:radio').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: Your solution is setting the checked to all the *radio* buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".radio1 li:nth-child(4)").find('input:radio').prop('checked',true);
$(".radio2 li:nth-child(2)").find('input:radio').prop('checked',true);
$(".radio li:nth-child(1)").find('input:radio').prop('checked',true);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  Fourth child selected:
<ul class="radio1">
   <li>
     <input id="1" type="radio" value="1" name="option1">
     <label >one</label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="2" type="radio" value="2" name="option1">
     <label >two</label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="3" type="radio" value="3" name="option1">
     <label >three</label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="4" type="radio" value="4" name="option1">
     <label >four</label>
   </li>
 </ul>
  Second child selected:
<ul class="radio2">
   <li>
     <input id="1" type="radio" value="1" name="option2">
     <label >one</label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="2" type="radio" value="2" name="option2">
     <label >two</label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="3" type="radio" value="3" name="option2">
     <label >three</label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="4" type="radio" value="4" name="option2">
     <label >four</label>
   </li>
 </ul>
  First child selected:
<ul class="radio">
   <li>
     <input id="1" type="radio" value="1" name="option">
     <label >one</label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="2" type="radio" value="2" name="option">
     <label >two</label>
   </li>   
 </ul>
  
   First child selected:(same class name)
  <ul class="radio">
   <li>
     <input id="1" type="radio" value="1" name="option4">
     <label >one</label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="2" type="radio" value="2" name="option4">
     <label >two</label>
   </li>   
 </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even the use of:

```
$(".myOptionList li:nth-child(2)").find('input:radio').prop('checked',true);
```

Works apparently, it is just for a case.

It set the checked on all the *radio* until the last one, that it is set just because it is the last.

A more meaning solution would be to use the *.last()* to go directly on the *radio* option you want to set:

```js
$(function(){

  // Set the last checked radio
  $('.myOptionList li > input[name="options"]').last().prop('checked', true)
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myOptionList">
   <li>
     <input id="1" type="radio" value="1" checked name="options">
     <label >one</label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input id="2" type="radio" value="2" name="options">
     <label >two</label>
   </li>
   ...
 </ul>
```

To ensure it's working properly I set the first *radio* checked.

But I suggest to change your code in a way that you select the *radio* on the *value* attribute.

The benefit of this is that your code will be more clear and easy to understand and change, and more if the order of radios change it will still works.